# Facebook blank canvas page from php if $_COOKIE statement

Tags: php, facebook, cookies

I'm using Facebook Php SDK v3.22 which I have JavaScript set me a cookie that is read in Php

For some reason when I use an if statement like so:

```
if($_COOKIE['anything'] == 'some_data'){
//do something
}
```

My canvas page redirects to a blank page with no error caught upon logout

I see in my page info that there are no cookies in the framed canvas page but I'm a little confused as I'm using server side Php to read the cookies and how this can result in Facebook redirecting to a blank page when ever I use an if cookie statement, it's sorcery!

I'm setting my cookies with JavaScript like so:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (self != top) {;
    var onsite = 'true'; document.cookie = 'domainname.com' + "=" + onsite;
}else{
    var onsite = 'false'; document.cookie = 'domainname.com' + "=" + onsite;
}
-->
</script>
```

Comment: what is the output of `print_r($_COOKIE);` (after your cookie is set)?

Comment: It's the expected output from how it was set!, it doesn't seem to matter what I set the cookie data to, this only happens when I try to read the cookie in a php if statement

Comment: can you post the `var_dump` of your `$_COOKIE` on your question. I suspect the cookie value has some leading/trailing line feed or some other invisible char.

Comment: There are no trailing slashes to be seen (O-o) however I have two equal keys in the cookie array: ["domainname_com"]=> string(5) "false" ["domainname.com"]=> string(5) "blank" php seems to read domainname_com and I set the 'blank' value as a default in php, it appears that the cookies set with JavaScript rewrite the domainname.com to domainname_com and despite php setting the default value as domainname.com it seems to read only domainname_com, the mystery deepens!.

Comment: based on your `$_COOKIE` var_dump key => value pair, what exactly are you trying to evaluate in your if statement in your PHP script?

Comment: I am evaluating if a value in the cookie is equal to == or not equal to != what ever value I set, at the moment I am looking for values 'true' and 'false'.

Comment: How are you setting the cookie? can you show your code.

Comment: if (self != top) {;
 var onsite = 'true'; document.cookie = 'domainname.com' + "=" + onsite;
}else{
var onsite = 'false'; document.cookie = 'domainname.com' + "=" + onsite;
}

Answer (score 0):

Use the following javascript on your Page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Set cookie function
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays) {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

// Set the cookie
var onsite = 'false',
    domain = 'domainname.com';
if (self != top) {
    onsite = 'true';
}
setCookie(domain, onsite);

</script>
```

And your PHP script will look like this:

```
<?php

// Test cookie
$domain = 'domainname.com';
if (isset($_COOKIE[$domain])) {
    if ($_COOKIE[$domain] == 'true') {
        // domainname.com is equal to 'true'
    } else {
        // domainname.com is NOT equal to 'true'
    }
} else {
    // cookie is not set yet
}

?>
```

*Note if you are trying to read the cookie before it's set, it wont really work.

Comment: The problem is, Facebook redirects to a blank page upon logout if I place an 'if cookie statement' anywhere in php!!!, if however I delete the cookie php 'if  statement', my logout redirects to the correct page, this is unaffected by what my php 'if statement' is doing after it has evaluated the cookie

Comment: I think your right about reading the $_COOKIE as when I remove the $_COOKIE['domainname.com'] = 'blank'; from above the 'if statemant' Facebook redirects to the correct page however the mystery as to why does Facebook do this remains, it is a piece of server side Php and nothing to do with redirection, I really appreciate your help :)